# Why does the CursorAdapter (using a ContentProvider) load data on the UI Thread?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, performance

Looking at the CursorAdapter code on github ([core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java))

The getView method calls mCursor.moveToPosition

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (!mDataValid) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
    }
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
    }
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = newView(mContext, mCursor, parent);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }
    bindView(v, mContext, mCursor);
    return v;
}
```

When I look at the CursorAdapter code here there will be cases where fillWindow gets called [core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java)

```
@Override
public boolean onMove(int oldPosition, int newPosition) {
    // Make sure the row at newPosition is present in the window
    if (mWindow == null || newPosition < mWindow.getStartPosition() ||
            newPosition >= (mWindow.getStartPosition() + mWindow.getNumRows())) {
        fillWindow(newPosition);
    }

    return true;
}
```

If you keep going through the code you'll see that this will eventually make a database call. What are the reasons for doing the database call on the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that the windowed aspect of the cursor is intended to be hidden from the
caller, so it isn't possible to avoid hitting the DB from the main thread while going from the first window to a spill over window using the current APIs.

Most queries fit into a single window though, so it's common practice to call getCount() on the cursor inside your AsynTask or Loader before handing it back to the UI thread, which has the side effect of loading the first window.